# existence of limit.

Tags: analysis, limits, metric-spaces

Let $(M_1,d_1)$ and $(M_2,d_2)$ be metric spaces and $f:A \rightarrow M_2$ is a function, where $A$ is a non empty subset of $M_1$. Assume $p$ is a limit point of $A$ and for every sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $A-\{p\}$ , sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$ is convergent to some point in $M_2$.

Does the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)$ exist?

I tried proof by contradiction by I got stuck in inequalities and I am starting to think that the limit does not necessarily exist. any ideas??

Comment: Is the space M_2 complete ?

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima not necessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can prove that $f$ is continuous. Let $B \subset M_2$ be a closet set. Now consider $f^{-1}(B)$ and $a$ be a limit point of it. Then we have a sequence $\{x_n\} \in f^{-1}(B)$ s.t. $\lim x_n = a$. Now consider the sequence $\{y_n\}$ defined by $y_{2k+1} = a, y_{2k} = x_k$. Then we have that $f(y_k) \to b$ by the contition. But also we have that $f(y_{2k+1}) \to b \implies f(a) \to b$, but then obviously $b=f(a)$, as $f(a)$ is a constant subsequence. So similarly $f(y_{2k}) \to b \implies f(x_k) \to f(a)$. So $f(a)$ is a limit point of $B$ and as $B$ is closed we have that $f(a) \in B \implies a \in  f^{-1}(B)$, so $f^{-1}(B)$ is closed, as it contains all of it's limit points. This proves that $f$ is continuous.

Now by the continuity of $p$ we have that the limit exists and $\lim_{x \to p} f(x) = f(p)$

Answer (score 1):

Take two sequences $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ in $A-\{p\}$ converging to $p$. Define a new one by
$$
z_n=\begin{cases}
x_{n/2} & \text{$n$ even}\\[4px]
y_{(n-1)/2} & \text{$n$ odd}
\end{cases}
$$
The sequence $\{f(z_n)\}$ is convergent by assumption. What can you say now about $\{f(x_n)\}$ and $\{f(y_n)\}$?

What can you conclude?